# Closed form solution of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my systems class we have to use the solution of a dynamical equation to model a system. It is a term project. The equation is given as
$$y''(x)+(x+1)y(x)=0\quad\text{ with the initial conditions}\quad y(0)=0\quad y'(0)=1$$
There is a closed form solution with elementary functions? My instructor told me the solution is found to be with some special functions; but as said I need some elementary functions. I tried every method I know but no progress yet. Can you show me some direction?

Edit: I need a solution in $[0,1]$

Comment: Oh no...I suggest not look for elementary functions, just stick to the special function you have. I don't understand why you need elementary functions.

Comment: I dont think there is a closed form solution with elementary functions. I agree with @ShuhaoCao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is closely related to the Airy equation

\begin{equation}
y''(x)-xy(x)=0
\end{equation}

And you can express its solutions fairly easily in terms of Airy functions. Don't see how you're going to get anywhere looking for elementary expressions, although they can be expressed as improper integrals of trig functions and exponentials. Is that what you're after?